# Remove # from value (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, href

```
var current = $(this).attr('href');
alert(current);
```

shows the value with '#' eg '#target' instead of just 'target', what do I modify in the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var current = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
alert(current);
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're dealing with a `<a>` element?

```
this.hash.substring(1); // yes, it's that simple...
```

Answer (score 1):

As easy as this, just use `replace`:

```
var current = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
```