# Get the url parameters and display it on jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good Day

I usually do things with PHP and when I have come into this jquery ui which is a good feature I had bump into some issues. I am fairly new to the javascript and jquery environment and still coping up with how it works.

My goal is to pass the parameter from a link into jquery dialog box and display that detail there.

HTML ANCHOR TAG

```
 <td><a href="#?ID=<?php echo $row ['ID']; ?>" id="showdialog"><?php if ($row ['AFFILIATION'] == FALSE) { echo "D"; } else { echo $row ['AFFILIATION']; } ?></a></td>
```

JQUERY DIALOG BOX

```
 <script>
     $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            height: 380,
            width: 280
        });

      $("a#showdialog").click(function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
 </scipt>
```

I have been reading a lot of threads all over the net but since I am still a novice at js I am not sure which one to use nor how I will put it in my dialog box.

Your suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to show the link in the dialog? or do you want to show the content of the page that the link points to in the dialog?

Comment: @th1rdey3 thanks for taking time to reply. I want to display the value from the link ID=<?php echo $row ['ID']; ?>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this).attr('href');` to get href or link address

```
<script>
     $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            height: 380,
            width: 280
        });

      $("a#showdialog").click(function(){
            // Use this to get href
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog").append(href)
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
 </scipt>
```

Comment: @Roy thanks a lot it worked, Follow up question how do you trim the #? from the link?

Comment: use can use this $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');

Comment: you can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156077/remove-from-value-jquery

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to show the id then you need to split your `href`

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {  
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  href = href.substring(2,href.length);
  var items = href.split('=');
  console.log(items);
});
```

`items[1]` will contain only the number.

<kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3u5s8pq4/2/)</kbd>